# Two divs on top of each other each taking the full height (and width) of the browser screen

Tags: css, html, height

I have two divs in my page and I would like both to have its width and height set to the width and height of the browser, so that I have to scroll down to see the second div.

How is this possible?

Eidt: I forgot to mention that I also want the content in these divs to be vertically centered.

What I did until now is taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css#6182661) links first answer and put that code into another div, which takes 100% of the height.

Here is what I have at the moment:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="first"><div class="outer"><div class="middle"><div class="inner"><h1>Title 1</h1></div></div></div></div>
    <div id="second"><div class="outer"><div class="middle"><div class="inner"><h1>DTitle 2</h1></div></div></div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
display: table;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.middle {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}

#first, #second {
height: 100%;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: With a little CSS. Have you tried any?

Comment: @j08691: The resulting window will be *twice* the height of the browser window.  Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey- You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9QuF6/1?

Comment: Please see the edit. I forgot to mention that I would also like to have the content inside the divs vertically centered (and if I do this it won't work anymore).

Comment: Oh well, I forgot to say that body should have a height of 100%. Well, thank you all for your fast help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

**HTML**

```
html, body { height:100%; }
.box { height:100%; }
.one { background:#eee; }
.two {  background:#ccc; }
```

**CSS**

```
<div class="box one">1</div>
<div class="box two">2</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AnyBB/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to say that body/html should have a height of 100%, which fixed it for me! :)